# User input to database

Tags: database, users, forms

I have given up all hope. Let me start with that.

**Goal:**

- User inputs data into a form (preferable one that looks clean and is scalable across platforms)
- User presses submit and the information is processed through a basic math formula
- That info is the updated in that users database table record (database is already made and working)
- The page refreshes to update the generated table on the page

**Why I am struggling:**

Other then I have less brain cells then a kiwi (bird or fruit), I can seem to find a plugin that lets you take user information and enter it into a database... I have Elementor pro, but it's forms don't let you do anything with database updating that I have seen/found. No other form plugin I have tried can save to a database for whatever reason.

Am I wrong to think that this should be an extremely basic idea and should be well documented and easy to achieve as a creator?

**Specific Use Case:**

Keeping track of users weights lifted for specific exercises.

Basic table fields:
ustats_id (primary key auto_increment),
user_id (ties the user to the table),
squat int,
deadlift int,
etc.

- User selects from a dropdown what exercise to update
- User enters weight lifted
- User enters reps completed
- User submits information
- Fancy formula spits out a number based on this
- That users exercise number is updated

To pull the information I have had to use the custom php with the $wpdb class, but I don't even know how to begin using the same to update the information (I have tried and failed miserably for about 30 hours now).

Is there an easier way? Am I stuck with having to make forms and shortcode in the php? I don't even know where to begin...

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

echo <<<EOF

<form action="I don't actually understand what goes here" method="post">
 <p> <select id="exercise" name="exercise">
       <option value="squat">Squat</option>
       <option value="deadlift">Deadlift</option>
       <option value="cry">Cry</option>
     </select></p>
 <p>Weight Lifted: <input type="number" name="weight" /></p>
 <p>Reps Completed: <input type="number" name="reps" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>

EOF;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if(the form submit is triggered){
$stat=weight*reps;
$wpdb->update( "UPDATE xxxxxx_userstats SET exercise=$stat WHERE user_id=$current_user->user_id");

}

?>
```

Or something, but I also know I have to care about SQL injection, but I can't even get this to work, let alone the data validation that I would have to do on top of it. If anyone has any ideas, or suggestions I would very much appreciate it.

I'm so lost.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. You are trying to kill two birds with one stone. In other words, there are several things you need to achive. To get there, you need to sort things out one after another. It's not undoable but pretty big to explain in one go (one post). Chop it into smaller pieces.

Comment: My problem is I don't even know where to chop it into smaller pieces, or where to start, or if there is just a better option then manually building it. It feels like it should be straight forward and simple. Data in -> straight to database. Really don't understand why it needs to be so complicated. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The complexity comes from the logic and understanding of how the data relates, how it's securely added via the front end etc.  For example, when someone's inputting 'weight lifted/number of reps" and that is assigned to their user stats, what happens to a previous entry? Are these data sets iterations or does the newest set remove previous sets?  There's a lot of consideration to be given to how things related, how they're organized, how they're retrieved and every use case is different. That's why there isn't a single 'catch all' plugin to manage this.